# R Plot Adds Extra Unwanted Line

Tags: r, plot, line-plot

I'm generating a simple line plot in R, however it adds another unwanted straight horizontal line to my plot that I don't want. And it happens in all of my line plots. I have tried google, however it only gives me instructions on how to add an extra line and not why this is happening. I am using RStudio 0.98.1028 on Mac OS X Yosemite.

```
plot(data2$interval,data2$steps,main="Plot of Average Activity", 
            xlab = "Interval", type="l", ylab="Average steps taken")
```

[image]

Comment: Let me point out that you really shouldn't plot a line in the first place. Experimental data points should be plotted as **points**, and a theoretical or fitted curve could be added as a line plot. The reason for this rule is that you do **not** know how your system behaves where you don't have data, and filling in a line can be highly misleading.

Answer (score 4):

I guess the problem is with your data. You might have rows at the end of the data frame that "return" to the origin. Here you have a reproducible example:

```
data2 <- data.frame(interval = 1:200, steps = rnorm(200, 50, 20))
data2[1,2] <- 0
data2[200,2] <- 0
data2[201, ] <- c(0, 0)


plot(data2$interval,data2$steps,main="Plot of Average Activity", 
     xlab = "Interval", type="l", ylab="Average steps taken")
```

please vote if the answer is fine with you :)

[image]

Comment: hi, added the figure - please rollback the change if you dont want

Comment: This is without a doubt the reason.